# Implicit generated members and noexcept

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I recently started to add the new `noexcept` specification to move constructors/assignments wherever possible. Now I started to wonder what the exception specification of implicit generated member functions looks like. Since having `noexcept` move functions allows the use of more efficient code paths(e.g. when resizing a `vector`) I would hope that those are declared as noexcept whenever possible. I had problems understanding what the standard has to say about that and therefore tried the following code in g++4.6 (with `-std=c++0x`) to get some grip on it:

```
struct foobar{};
int main()
{
    foobar a, b;
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha
             <<noexcept(foobar())<<", "<<noexcept(foobar(a))<<", "
             <<noexcept(a = b)   <<", "<<noexcept(a = std::move(b))<<", "
             <<noexcept(foobar(std::move(a)))<<std::endl;
}
```

This gave me an output of `True, True, True, False, False`, meaning that default and copy constructor/assignment where `noexcept`, while move operation where not.

Now for my question:

**Under what circumstances are implicit generated (or defaulted) member functions declared as `noexcept`? Furthermore is the obseved behaviour for `foobar` correct or simply a compiler bug in gcc4.6?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Library bug — it shows `true, true, true, true, true` in gcc 4.7.

And the bug is *not* that the generated move constructors aren't noexcept, but that `std::move` is not marked as `noexcept`, as we can see with the additional tests:

```
std::cout << noexcept(a = static_cast<foobar&&>(b)) << ", "  // true
          << noexcept(foobar(static_cast<foobar&&>(b))) << ", " // true
          << noexcept(std::move(b)) << std::endl;   // false
```

Most of the library functions in gcc 4.6 was not noexcept-correct, and this has been addressed in [gcc 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html#cxx),

---

As for when the implcitely generated member functions are noexcept, this is documented in §15.4/14. Basically, it is `noexcept` if all functions it will need to call are all `noexcept`.

> An implicitly declared special member function (Clause 12) shall have an *exception-specification*. If `f` is
>    an implicitly declared default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, destructor, copy assignment
>   operator, or move assignment operator, its implicit *exception-specification* specifies the *type-id* `T` if and only
>      if `T` is allowed by the *exception-specification* of a function directly invoked by `f`’s implicit definition; `f` shall
>           allow all exceptions if any function it directly invokes allows all exceptions, **and `f` shall allow no exceptions
>          if every function it directly invokes allows no exceptions.**

Comment: So does that mean that those functions are `noexcept` whenever possible (aka they don't call any throwing functions)?

Comment: @Grizzly: I think it means that they will be `noexcept` if they only call `noexcept` functions (i.e. whether the actual functions called throw or not is irrelevant, the exception specification is what matters)